# iOS Autoplay Video WebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios, webview

I want to add into the body a video (local video) that should be on auto play
Any easy solution for that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="fuctions/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="fuctions/cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="fuctions/functions.js"></script>
    </head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        checkFirstRun();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a property on UIWebView called mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction which defaults to YES. Change it to NO.

Comment: alread is set to no but what the html code must be like for the autoplay?

Comment: In you video tag set the autoplay attribute

Comment: <a href="movie.mp4">
                    <span class="image" style="background-image: url('images/video.png')"></span>
                    <span class="name">Tutorial Video Ansehen</span>
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
</a>

Looks like that right now

Comment: You've lost me, you're trying to put a link to a video, not play a video in the view?

Comment: Worth noting that the new-ish (as of writing) WKWebView has moved this to a preference in WKWebViewConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Apple and Google decided to allow autoplay in their mobile browsers. But only if videos are muted. On iOS you also have to set the playsinline attribute, because by default videos will play fullscreen.

To get autoplay use the following setup:

```
<video controls autoplay loop muted playsinline>

<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

<source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">

</video>
```